# Naming nodes in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm playing with the [distributed programming tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#3.4) from the 5.4 documentation, and have run into a problem with node names.

My MacBook's default name (`jamess-macbook`) does not play well with Erlang's node-naming scheme, due to the dash:

```
(salt@jamess-macbook)4> {my_process, pepper@jamess-macbook} ! start
** exception error: bad argument in an arithmetic expression
     in operator  -/2
        called as pepper@jamess - macbook
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to get around this, short of renaming all the machines I want to run Erlang on, but I can't see it in the documentation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to quote the atom properly. `'pepper@jamess-macbook'` (with the single quotes) is the name of the node.

> An atom should be enclosed in single
>   quotes (') if it does not begin with a
>   lower-case letter or if it contains
>   other characters than alphanumeric
>   characters, underscore (_), or @.
>   -- [Erlang Reference Manual](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#2.3)

Using short node names (`-sname`) has various other consequences (limited interoperability with long node name nodes, doesn't load dns information into inet_db and so on).

Comment: Even better - I had tried double quotes, not single; in fact, I didn't realise they were semantically different!

Answer (score 5):

Start the Erlang interpreter with:

```
$ erl -sname node_name
```

where `node_name` is the name you want to use to refer to the machine.

You can even simulate a distributed system on a single machine by starting several instances of the interpreter, each with a different node name.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could supply the full node name (name@machine) through sname!